# Make Access wait for a file to become available using VBA?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, wait

So here is the situation. So I have some software called bartender that constantly checks a microsoft Access database for changes in order to print labels automatically. The problem is that every time bartender checks the database, it will lock all other applications from writing to the file.

So I need my access VBA program to wait until the file becomes available again before exporting all data to the database being watched by bartender. Every once in awhile when I export data to the database it is already open by bartender, causing an error.

This is my SQL statement I am executing in order to export all data to the database being watched:

"INSERT INTO G:\OPS\Nameplate\2x3Labels\LABELPRINT.accdb.LABEL_PRINT SELECT * FROM MASTER_STANDARD"

So How can I got about making my access program wait until this file is available for opening to send the data?

Thank you all ahead of time for the help.

Comment: Write a status in a text file about whose turn it is and both bartender and the VBA program check the file. The file contains something like "bartender" when bartender is reading the file, and the VBA must wait till the file becomes empty. Then the VBA changes the file to "VBA" and do some stuff to the data. When the bartender checks the file, it can't access the data because it's being hold by other program.

Comment: You should just be linking the table from your remote db. Not sure why you're having a problem appending data to a shared database.

Comment: Is there a .laccdb file (G:\OPS\Nameplate\2x3Labels\LABELPRINT.laccdb) while Bartender checks the file? If so, wait until it's gone.